# file access universal windows filepicker

Tags: windows-10-universal, fileopenpicker

Im using the FileOpenPicker to let the User choose a file (sqlite-db), which can be anywhere on the computer:

```
public async Task<string> PickDb()
{
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = null;
    var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".sqlite");                 
    file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
        return file.Path;
    else
        return string.empty;
}
```

This filename is then passed over to sqlite to open a sqlite-connection.

So if the sqlite-file is in the apps home directory, the sqlite-connection is properly opened. If the file is somewhere else, the sqlite-connection gives an read-error.

I know, that UWP-Apps have limited acces to the the filesystem. but as far as I understood, a file returned by a FileOpenPicker, which was manually picked by the user, has always read-write rights.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: But in your case you're using the path of the file. Use the direct reference to the file don't try accessing via its path, this is why you're getting an error

Comment: I must, because the sqlite-api needs the path as string.

Comment: What error are you exactly getting?

Comment: var r = SQLite3.Open(databasePath, out handle, (int)openFlags, IntPtr.Zero);
r is SQLite3.Result.CannotOpen